# Angular - Highcharts - Color b/w points

Tags: angular, highcharts, colors, zone

I'm a newbie to Angular. I started working with Highcharts. I want to plot line series with multi colors. I'm able to do it with zones, but my requirement is bit different. I want to assign color for each line between points - either for the charts of line type or spline.

Is it possible to plot a line series with different color - irrespective of zones?

[image: required chart image]

Comment: post your trying

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something similar like in zones by adding a few series type scatter and connect them **lineWidth**.

For better clarity, to make the scatter plot look like a line, you can disable the point **marker.enabled**.

```
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
      lineWidth: 2,
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
      data: [{
          x: 1,
          y: 10
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 15
        }
      ],
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      data: [{
          x: 2,
          y: 15
        },
        {
          x: 3,
          y: 25
        }
      ],
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      data: [{
          x: 3,
          y: 25
        },
        {
          x: 4,
          y: 5
        }
      ],
      color: 'green'
    },
  ],
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6f8noxLr/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.marker.enabled
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.lineWidth

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, Working Fine . But with this case Multiple Series is getting Plotted which results in Huge Memory Consumption. Is there any way to achieve within Single Series.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Shivabharathi Ponnuvelu,
You can try with gradient I guess.
https://jsfiddle.net/9L3f0w8h/29/

https://www.demo2s.com/javascript/javascript-highcharts-spline-chart-gradient-fill.html

```
lineColor: {
    linearGradient: [0,0,0,1],
    stops: [       
        [0, 'green'],
        [0.5, 'red'],
        [1, 'blue']
    ]
}
```

Is there any specific reason you want to use this without zones?